# CSS specificity selector: element selector overrides pseudo class

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

Im new in CSS, i was learning about CSS element specificity, and I know that at the end the selector with more specificity will be applied, but how about this case:
[image]

this supposed to be more specific

```
    header: first-child {
        color: red:
    }
```

why is not applied???

Comment: The space between header: and first-child means it thinks its a child of header to apply colour. Remove the space. ie header:first-child

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specificity only affects the element that is selected.

`h1 { color: blue; }` is not competing with `header:first-child { color: red; }` because they target different elements.

`h1 { color: blue; }` is competing with `h1 { color: inherit; }` from the browser's default stylesheet (and wins because author stylesheets beat browser stylesheets).